# media query works with display option

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

I have attached this media query with my css class.

CSS

```
  @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .details{
       display:block;
    }
}

.details{

  margin-left: 20px;
   font-size: 15px; 
    color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
 <p class="details" > My career has taken a natural progression fro m client websites, to UI templates, to simple php websites, to Laravel framework. </p>
```

My problem is that in the media query class, whatever I write instead of `display` nothing works. I am trying to give a different color `color:blue` and but the color remains same.

what is the issue?

Comment: Move your media query below the .details{} in your css and it should work.

Comment: @FlorinSimion it worked thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move media query to bottom of details class.

when you set a property for a class or id more than once, the last one affects the class or id.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order:

```
.details{

  margin-left: 20px;
   font-size: 15px; 
    color: black;
} 
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .details{
       display:block;
      color: blue;
    }
}
```